# How to Convert Arrays to Vector Pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to convert an array to a vector pointer. I tried using std::copy, however, this produced a SegFault error. Is there any way to do this?
Thank you so much and I really appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
  int myints[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
  std::vector<int> *myvector (7);
  std::copy ( myints, myints+7, *myvector->begin() );
}
```

Comment: Your obvious intent is to take an array of seven values, and end up with a vector of seven pointers, one pointer to each value in the array. This is not how `std::copy` works, and you cannot use it. That's not what it does. Aside from correctly declaring `std::vector<int *>` as the vector's type, you need to initialize the vector yourself.

Comment: *I am trying to convert an array to a vector pointer* Please reconsider this. In order to make a pointer to a `vector` usable you must have a `vector` to point at, and this suggests you are going to dynamically allocate one. The entire point of `vector` is to look after the messiness of dynamic memory management for you, so dynamically allocating a `vector` and having to manage it yourself is a step backward. You almost never want a pointer to a `vector`. A modern compiler is quite skilled at eliminating copying of them as you pass them around and references handle the remaining cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely convinced that you actually want a pointer to a vector, since it seems unlikely that that would be the case (also `std::vector<int> *myvector(7);` doesn't instantiate a vector it creates a pointer to `std::vector`. If you want to instantiate a vector, this works:

`std::vector<int> myVector(myInts, myInts + (sizeof(myInts)/sizeof(*myInts)));`

Otherwise,

pointer:

`auto myVector = new std::vector<int>(myInts, myInts + (sizeof(myInts)/sizeof(*myInts)));`

smartPointer:

`auto myVector = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(myInts, myInts + (sizeof(myInts)/sizeof(*myInts)));`

Comment: Mind you, if your compiler's fairly up to date, you can [use `std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) instead of the `sizeof` rigmarole.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

int main () {
  int myints[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
  auto myvector = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(7);
  std::copy ( myints, myints+7, myvector->begin() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this conversion to a regular vector would be. Using a vector pointer is not a good idea because it can cause unwanted behavior. Also your vector pointer was never actually constructed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
  int myints[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
  std::vector<int> myvector (7);
  std::copy ( myints, myint+7, myvector.begin() );
}
```